# Application not running at full speed?

Tags: performance, io, cpu, disk

I have the following scenario:

- machine 1: receives messages from outside and processes them (via a
  Java application). For processing it relies on a database (on machine
  2)
- machine 2: an Oracle DB

As performance metrics I usually look at the value of processed messages per time.

Now, what puzzles me: none of the 2 machines is working on "full speed". If I look at typical parameters (CPU utilization, CPU load, I/O bandwidth, etc.) both machines look as they have not enough to do.

What I expect is that one machine, or one of the performance related parameters limits the overall processing speed. Since I cannot observe this I would expect a higher message processing rate.

Any ideas what might limit the overall performance? What is the bottleneck?

Here are some key values during workload:

Machine 1:

- CPU load average: 0.75
- CPU Utilization: System 12%, User 13%, Wait 5%
- Disk throughput: 1 MB/s (write), almost no reads
- average tps (as reported by iostat): 200
- network: 500 kB/s in, 300 kB/s out, 1600 packets/s in, 1600 packets/s out

Machine 2:

- CPU load average: 0.25
- CPU Utilization: System 3%, User 15%, Wait 17%
- Disk throughput: 4.5 MB/s (write), 3.5 MB/s (read)
- average tps (as reported by iostat): 190 (very short peaks to 1000-1500)
- network: 250 kB/s in, 800 kB/s out, 1100 packets/s in, 1100 packets/s out

So for me, all values seem not to be at any limit.

PS: for testing of course the message queue is always full, so that both machines have enough work to do.

Comment: + for a well-written question. In general, any program will spend part of its time running the CPU, and part of it waiting for I/O (which is just a different CPU). Messages per time is a good metric. Utilization percent is not. Poor performance could be reflected in low utilization, or in high utilization. As @Mahol25 says, you need to look *inside* the app to find sources of slowness.

Answer (score 1):

To find bottlenecks you typically need to measure also INSIDE the application. That means profiling the java application code and possibly what happens inside Oracle.

The good news is that you have excluded at least some possible hardware bottlenecks.

Comment: I would understand that if e.g. machine 1 uses 100% CPU, then the next obvious investigation would include the application - but 100% at least would tell me that the applications is working "all the time".

The point is: if e.g. CPU is at 25% (and I/O is not an obvious problem): what prevents the application from running at 4x the speed? I'm not sure how application profiling can give me an answer to that.

Comment: One obvious possibility is that the application is written as a single threaded application where that thread is working 100 % of the time on one CPU core, but your machine has four CPU cores, of which three are completely idle because of how the application code was written. This is just one example.

Comment: I guess I can rule out his reason: I was watching the CPU load on both machines via top (showing all CPU cores): the main process on machine 1 had values around 20 on 1 core (single-threaded,2 cores available), the oracle process on machine 2 had values around 35 on 1 used core (peaks up to 50, 4 cores available). So on none of the 2 machines a single core is working fully.